# Having on trying to learn how to make a simple scala actor

Tags: scala, actor

I'm trying to grasp scala actors (I'm reading "Scala for the Impatient") and the following short example is not working like I intended.

I have case classes of messages I want to send to the actor:

```
abstract class Message
case class Sum(x: Int, y: Int) extends Message
case class Stop() extends Message
```

And how the actor should process them:

```
import scala.actors.Actor

class Adder(val idx: Int) extends Actor {

  def act() {
    while(true) {
      receive {
        case Sum(x: Int, y: Int) => println("Total: " + (x+y) + ", by " + idx)
        case Stop => exit()
        case _ => println("Wrong message sent to: " + idx  + "!")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the main object I create an Adder instance and send some messages:

```
object Main extends App{
  val adder = new Adder(0)
  println("Init")
  adder ! "Rafael"
  adder ! Sum(2, 3)
  adder ! Sum(5, 6)
  adder ! Stop()
  println("goodbye!")
}
```

But the only outputs are the prints of "Init" and "goodbye!". I can't seem to find what's wrong with the code. I had some working actors before trying this one and just used the same pattern. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program exits before actors gets messages.

You could add `Thread.sleep(1000)` before `println("goodbye!")` as hotfix.

Instead of `Thread.sleep` you could wait for answer from you actor. In this case actor should reply on `Stop` message.

Note that scala actors are deprecated, so you should use [akka](http://akka.io) actors.

Also case classes with no arguments are deprecated, use `case object Stop extends Message` instead of `case class`.

Comment: Hum... Makes sense! I understand now why my previous example worked: I had an infinite loop requesting messages from stdin, so I always had time to see the msgs being processed. I'll follow your tips. Thanks!

Seems my book is seriously outdated though. Do you know what version of scala Martin Odersky's book contemplate?

Comment: @RafaelS.Calsaverini: you could use [akka documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.4/) for actors and [scala documentation site](http://docs.scala-lang.org/index.html) for many other topics. For instance if you want to use some tutorial on scala actors with akka actors [The Scala Actors Migration Guide](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/actors-migration-guide.html) could be helpful.

Comment: @EndreVarga: I'm not a native English speaker. Please tell me how to fix this sentence to make it more clear: "Note that scala actors are deprecated, so you should use akka actors."

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I didn't see you mentioned it explicitly -- I just saw your above comment linking to the Akka docs.